# Twitter Bootstrap - Using Button Dropdown - Menu mis-aligned

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to create Button dropdowns, but the inner menu buttons seems not to align just under it. The dropdown is at center of the page and the menu is appearing at the extreme left of the page.

I had tried using LEFT, PADDING, MARGIN-LEFT attributes but no success.

Code:

```
<span class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Export
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style=" margin-left:498;" >
        <!-- dropdown menu links -->
        <li>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" onclick="btnExportExcel_Click">Excel</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>

         <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="btnExportCSV_Click">CSV</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Comment: can you have a screen shot of your page and the underlying html(view sourced) here...

Comment: Sorry, I tried that, but I dont have access to upload files on internet.

Comment: Simply, the menu shown at(http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns) are aligned just under the button, however mine are not, they are towards extereme left of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could even try this...

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
     <!-- dropdown menu links -->
    <li>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" onclick="btnExportExcel_Click">Excel</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>

     <li>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="btnExportCSV_Click">CSV</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>...
  </ul>
</div>
```

you would be required to add `bootstrap-dropdown.js` if you are not using a full bootstrap.js compilation.

Comment: Friend, we both seems to be newbies..! I had this same idea of using dropdowns! It too have same problem, menu is going down & left. And I had full bootstrap. Also, It works well when I am putting the button into nextline.

Comment: well I am a newbie to bootstrap but m pretty well versed with html.. and I feel i could do something if I had your html in my hands... well from ur descrptions it seems the container `<div class="btn-group">` or any of its ancestor tags might be using `position` property in a bad way... just check for any position property around the tag

Comment: Man! You solved it..! Thank you! There was an open <p> tag up in the body..! "its ancestor tags might be using position` property in a bad way"  - Wow!

Comment: well actually i dint mean that.. but yes I meant that ur html might be broken in other ways...:)

Answer (score 1):

I think the markup for the button-group specifies to use a `<div class="btn-group">` instead of `span`. Try with div there

Comment: This is outer tag. If I use **DIV** then button comes to next line (left of the page), but I dont want my button to go to next line, so I am using **SPAN** tag, with this button is staying on proper position but its sub-menu is going left-down. Hope its clear what I tried to say.

Comment: in that case use <div class="btn-group"> and wrap this div inside a span.. `<span><div class="btn-group">...</div></span>`

Comment: oh then you might experiment this as well.....`<div class="btn-group" style="display:inline">`

Answer (score 0):

try to include in the class `pull-left` like this  `class='dropdown-menu pull-left'`